# Performing SQL-like join in Python and storing in nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

What would be the most optimal way to perform a SQL-like join in Python on two text files where I'm trying to retrieve the Name, Course, and Grade for each student? So something like `SELECT Students.name, Grades.Coursename, Grades.LetterGrade FROM Grades, Students WHERE Grades.ID = Students.ID`.

I can map the grades for any specific person by specifying the ID number by using list comprehension:

```
hello = [item for item in customfunction() if item[0]=='10103']
```

With list comprehensions and a dictionary for the specified ID:

```
hello = [['10103', 'SSW 567', 'A', '98765'], ['10103', 'SSW 564', 'A-', '98764'], ['10103', 'SSW 687', 'B', '98764'], ['10103', 'CS 501', 'B', '98764']]

#Get course names
b = [el[1] for el in hello]

#Get grades for each course
c = [el[2] for el in hello]

gradedict = {}

for el in b:
    for el2 in c:
        gradedict.update({el: el2})

print(gradedict)
```

The output - which has evidently incorrect output for the first two elements:

```
{'SSW 567': 'B', 'SSW 564': 'B', 'SSW 687': 'B', 'CS 501': 'B'}
```

And yet, `print(c)` yields `['A', 'A-', 'B', 'B']`.

In any case, how would I be able to efficiently do this for each ID in the files? Ideal output would be a nested dictionary, i.e.`{StudentName: {CourseName: Grade}}`

Grades.txt has this (separated by \t, i.e. a tab):

```
10103   SSW 567 A   98765
10103   SSW 564 A-  98764
10103   SSW 687 B   98764
10103   CS 501  B   98764
10172   SSW 555 A   98763
10172   SSW 567 A-  98765
```

Students.txt has this:

```
10103   Baldwin, C  SFEN
10172   Forbes, I   SFEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("Grades.txt", sep='\t', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv("Students.txt",sep='\t',header=None)
df1.columns = ["id", "degree", "etc"]
df2.columns = ["id", "name", "c"]
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id')
```

1. Load pandas library
2. Import two dataframes a s CSV with tab seperator
3. Set the columns
4. Make the Merge on id column

Comment: Is there a way I could sort by course name, and then by student name? I've tried `df3 = df[["name", "class", "lettergrade"]].sort_values(["class", "name"]).groupby("name").head(10)` but that just sorts by class on the entire list, and does not group by name at all

Comment: ```.groupby('id')``` did the trick, an additional column wasn't what I had originally hoped for, but end result is what I want

Answer (score 0):

1. Load each data as `pandas.DataFrame`
2. Use `merge` method of `pandas` library which will give you the `inner join`

Since your data is in `.txt`, you should load it like following

```
import pandas as pd
grades = pd.read_csv('Grades.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
students= pd.read_csv('Students.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
# set columns
grades.columns = ["id", "name", "etc."] 
students.columns = ["id", "name", "etc."]

# after loading two data as `pandas.DataFrame`, use `merge` to inner join

inner_join = pd.merge(grades, students, on='id')
```

Comment: Students.txt is also separated by \t

Comment: @JimT Good! Then you can read `Students.txt`  same as `Grades.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use multiple list comprehensions and a for loop, you can just use a list comprehension inside a dictionary to construct the gradedict you require as follows:

```
hello = [['10103', 'SSW 567', 'A', '98765'], ['10103', 'SSW 564', 'A-', '98764'], ['10103', 'SSW 687', 'B', '98764'], ['10103', 'CS 501', 'B', '98764']]                                                                                    
gradedict = {el[1]: el[2] for el in hello}
```

Comment: This does map the correct letter grade to each course, but how would I be able to match the set of grades for each student in a list of students?